Getting client namespace disconnected error on go socket io with client-side in react
I'm trying to create a simple web socket connection between the Go server and React client, but I'm unable to do so, I tried every step possible to solve this but couldn't.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.
Here is my server-side simple go code, using Gin as the framework. I'm trying golang for the first time here.
Using go-socket 1.7 version
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    app := gin.New()
    app.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"}, // Allow all origins for debugging
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    }))
    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)
    server.OnConnect("/", func(c socketio.Conn) error {
        c.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", c.ID())
        return nil
    })
    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        log.Println("Disconnected:", s.ID(), "Reason:", reason)
    })
    server.OnEvent("/", "chat msg", func (s socketio.Conn, msg string)  {
        log.Printf("Received message: %s", msg)
        s.Emit("chat msg", "Message received: "+msg)
    })
    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Socket.IO server failed to start: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()
    app.GET("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    app.POST("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    app.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    if err := app.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Gin server failed to start: %v", err)
    }
}



Here is my React Client Code - Using socket client version 4.7.5
import React, { FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client'
import { Box, Button, Paper, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material'

interface Messages{
    text: String,
    sentByCurrentUser: Boolean
}

const Chat = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Messages[]>([])
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket | null>(null)
    useEffect((): ReturnType<any> =>  {
        const newSocketConnection = io("http://localhost:8080")
        setSocket(newSocketConnection)
        newSocketConnection.on("chat msg", (messageReceived) => {
            console.log(" Received + " + messageReceived);
            setMessages((previousMessages: Messages[]) => [...previousMessages, {
                text: messageReceived,
                sentByCurrentUser: false
            }]);
        });
        return (): Socket => newSocketConnection.close();
    }, [])

    const sendMessage = (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (socket) {
            socket.emit("chat msg", message);
            setMessages((previousMessages: Messages[]) => [...previousMessages, {
                text: message,
                sentByCurrentUser: true
            }]);
            setMessage("")
        }
    }
  return (
          <Box sx={{ margin: 5 }}>
              <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="large"
                  onClick={(e) => sendMessage(e)}
              >Send Message</Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
  )
}
export default Chat

I'm trying to create a simple web socket connection between the Go server and React client, but I'm unable to do so, I tried every steps possible to solve this but couldn't.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

We can help you but you need to Tell us which Error did you have ?

When I change cors policies I get 403 forbidden error. Otherwise I just get "Client namespace disconnect". Not sure why I'm getting this.

You need to Post real Error Message so the full Error incl stacktraces. From Front and Backend. I dont know If the are connect once or not etc.... You Just Post your Code with any Things you are tried or helpful Infos. With more Infos we could Help.
